# Meaning of derivative of a vector wrt another vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Say I have vectors $I$, $o$ and $h$
$I$ is defined as $$I=-o+2(o \cdot h)h$$
What is the meaning of $\frac{dI}{dh}$?
I understand that it is equal to $4(o \cdot h)$, but what is the implication of this? To me, it would make sense if the result is also a vector, since my intuitive understanding is that the derivative describes how $I$ moves as $h$ changes.

Comment: In this case, $I$ is a function from $n$-space to itself, so the derivative is taken in the multivariable sense. Have you seen the formal definition of the multivariable derivative?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to rename the variables for clarity.  I'll replace $I$ with $F$, $h$ with $x$ and $ o$ with $y$, where $ x, y, F \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

So now we have,

$ F = - y + 2 (x \cdot y) x $

The derivative $\dfrac{dF}{d x} $ is defined as the matrix $J$ where the $(i,j)$-th entry is given by

$ J_{ij} = \dfrac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j} = \dfrac{\partial ( - y_i + 2 (x \cdot y) x_i )}{\partial x_j}$

Now, if $i = j$ then

$ J_{ii} = \dfrac{\partial ( - y_i + 2 (x \cdot y) x_i )}{\partial x_i}$

And this equals

$ J_{ii} = 2 (x \cdot y) + 2 x_i y_i $

If $i \ne j $, then

$ J_{ij} = \dfrac{\partial ( - y_i + 2 (x \cdot y) x_i )}{\partial x_j} = 2 x_i y_j $

Hence, combining the two cases,

$ J = 2 \ x \ y^T + 2 (x \cdot y) I_n $

where $I_n$ is the $n \times n $ identity matrix.